# Can I publish code I wrote at my internship?

Tags: internship

I have completed an internship under the guidance of my boss. Is it right to ask my boss to let me publish the source code in github, though the organisation I interned with will be using a modified version of it? FYI I already submitted the source code for my graduate project (It's an internship cum project) .

Comment: No  you do not own code developed in an internship or other professional employment and should not publish it in github or anywhere else. That is theft.

Comment: Thanks a lot for showin me the right path! I won't act unethical now! ( Upvote for you-only in words :(     coz of my rep. )

Comment: You say "my intern", and "Intern A". Do you mean the company that you interned with?

Comment: I'm just referring to the person who guided me during the internship in the organisation A.

Comment: The person who guides you is your boss - you are the intern. I reworded the question and title. If you would like to change anything, feel free to edit. Also, what is an "internship cum project"?

Comment: Got it! TY! I am submitting my internship work as my project in my university (tat's y internship cum project).

Comment: What country is this? Was this coordinated with your university? A lot of universities in Europe do much more coordinated internships with universities. In the USA this would not be a very good idea but there are probably documents your company/university signed discussing this.

Comment: Of course, I got this opportunity via my university! Ok, I understand that it's really a bad idea!

Comment: @HLGEM, you are patently wrong. In the US, there are internships for college credit, unpaid internships, etc., so the answer depends on the internship type. For unpaid internships, if no contract was signed, then *the intern owns all of their work.*

Comment: Woah!, Then I am able to publish the code? since there was no contract and I was unpaid!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must get a permission for it from your manager.

Sometimes such a request might look silly, sometimes it might make sense but chances are that your request will be rejected unless contributing to open source is in the culture of the company.

If it is something like a library for reasonable common problem, or you modified some open source project it might make sense to open source it. For example, the company might benefit from outsiders contributing to it.

But normally it has very little benefit, has some risk which makes it not worth it for the company.

Comment: TY for your advice :)